# gSOAP C client for accessing a Java web service

Tags: java, c, web-services, client, gsoap

I have created a Java web service and I am trying to access this web service from a gSOAP C client:

```
wsdl2h -c CalculatorService.wsdl
soapcpp2 -c -C CalculatorService.h
```

When I try to compile the files with this:

```
g++ -o ClientWS.exe ClientWS.c soapC.c soapClient.c C:\gsoap-2.8.9\gsoap\stdsoap2.c -IC:\gsoap-2.8.9\gsoap -IC:\gsoap-2.8.9\gsoap\import -LC:\GNUstep\lib\libws2_32.a
```

I am getting many `undefined reference` errors, as shown below:

> `C:\DOCUME~1\MPERIY~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccvFm9ql.o:stdsoap2.c:(.text+0x188): undefined reference to sendto@24'
>   C:\DOCUME~1\MPERIY~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccvFm9ql.o:stdsoap2.c:(.text+0x1b2): undefined reference tosend@16'
>   C:\DOCUME~1\MPERIY~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccvFm9ql.o:stdsoap2.c:(.text+0x280): undefined reference to sendto@24'
>   C:\DOCUME~1\MPERIY~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccvFm9ql.o:stdsoap2.c:(.text+0x2aa): undefined reference tosend@16'
>   C:\DOCUME~1\MPERIY~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccvFm9ql.o:stdsoap2.c:(.text+0x302): undefined reference to send@16'
>   C:\DOCUME~1\MPERIY~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccvFm9ql.o:stdsoap2.c:(.text+0x319): undefined reference toWSAGetLastError@0'
>   C:\DOCUME~1\MPERIY~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccvFm9ql.o:stdsoap2.c:(.text+0xad2): undefined reference to recvfrom@24'
>   C:\DOCUME~1\MPERIY~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccvFm9ql.o:stdsoap2.c:(.text+0xaf6): undefined reference tontohl@4'
>   C:\DOCUME~1\MPERIY~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccvFm9ql.o:stdsoap2.c:(.text+0xb29): undefined reference to recv@16'
>   C:\DOCUME~1\MPERIY~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccvFm9ql.o:stdsoap2.c:(.text+0xb3e): undefined reference toWSAGetLastError@0'
>   
> more errors like this...
>
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`

Can you provide a solution for how to link the missing files? I don't how the link and the include paths work, and where to search for libraries in C.

I have GNUstep and gSOAP in windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try -LC:\GNUstep\lib\ -lws2_32

```
g++ -o ClientWS.exe ClientWS.c soapC.c soapClient.c C:\gsoap-2.8.9\gsoap\stdsoap2.c -IC:\gsoap-2.8.9\gsoap -IC:\gsoap-2.8.9\gsoap\import -LC:\GNUstep\lib\ -lws2_32
```

The **-L** gives the *directory* where your library is located

the **-l** requests that the Link Editor add the named library to the those that are searched for references.

When nominating the library using -l you drop the lib and suffix.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for your suggestion, after following your steps. I am able to compile and client exe file is created and is running fine. I have accepted your answer.

Comment: Great stuff, Muthu! It's 20 years since I grappled with -L and -l but it's like riding a bike; once you learn it, you never forget it.